# Joins using more than two tables

Tags: oracle10g, obiee

How to join one table with more than two tables?

Comment: This is a general question, write a more specific one. What is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
select * from Table1 a
join table2 b on (a.column = b.column)
join table3 c on (a.column = c.column)
```

But I suggest you pick up a tutorial on how to write queries to decrease downtime on basic statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b JOIN c JOIN d
```

This will do a cartesian product because there is no join conditions, but `a` has been joined with three tables. Maybe your question needs to be more specific.

Comment: That syntax will thrown an error as the JOIN keyword requires an `ON` condition. For a cartesian product you need `CROSS JOIN` (which does not require an `ON` condition)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: you're completely right, I had not seen this was Oracle specific. I was thinking of SQLite (see [this](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause): *If the join-op is "CROSS JOIN", "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" or a comma (",") and there is no ON or USING clause, then the result of the join is simply the cartesian product of the left and right-hand datasets.*)

Comment: This is not Oracle specific. JOIN ... ON is the ANSI SQL Standard. I'm surprised that it works in SQLite without the ON. Never seen that before in other DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, DB2, H2, HSQLDB)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I mean, the question is Oracle specific (tagged Oracle)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 a,table2 b,table3 c where a.col=b.col and a.col=c.col
```